# Why isn't the "!=" operator working for me in C++ VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

A simple example：

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    string a="abc";
    string b="abc";
    if(a!=b)
        cout<<"abc";

}
```

this code can be compiled by mingw G++ ,but it can not be compiled by VS2012 and vs2010. I dont know why.

what should i do to make code can be compiled by VS2012 or vs2010

i found that the problem is the headfile but why it can work in G++？

Comment: include the original error please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change

`#include <cstring>`

which is the old, c-style `string.h` by

`#include <string>`

Which describe the `string` class that resides in the `std` namespace in C++.

Comment: @Steve314: Who says `<string>` is included as a side-effect of including `<iostream>`?

Comment: @Benjamin - Oops - I'm suffering from "didn't read the question properly". I didn't realise it was a compile-time error. Obviously if the code compiled, the `string` identifier was recognised - but that isn't happening here because the code doesn't compile, except maybe it *is* happening in GCC and that's why it compiles with that.

Comment: thanks for your help！did you mean that G++ wil not compile cstring？